# Actionscript mobile library project

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, flash-builder

I'm developing an **ActionScript 3.0** project for Blackberry Playbook, Android and iOS.

I have some custom UI classes, like buttons, that I want to use it in another projects.

How can I make an **actionscript mobile library project**?

I'm using Flash Builder 4.5, and I'm not using Flex in my code.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for. Do you want to create a swc with assets that you can reuse? Or are you looking for information about how to setup a project in Flash Builder?

Comment: I want a project with some classes that I can reuse in another projects.

Comment: Be careful with shared resources (assets/libraries/projects...) — they could be changed one day, and therefore some of the old projects could be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create ActionScript project, then add it to your mobile project's references (as a source.) Or create Flex library and link it with mobile project.

Answer (score 3):

Using Flash Builder 4.5:

- choose File > Project > New
- choose "library project"
- check the "include AIR features" box.

This will compile a .swc, a binary file you can distribute easily.

Including AIR in this .swc ensures that all the mobile-oriented features will be compiled as well, i.e. TouchEvent.

Flex classes, that you're not using, won't be included.